# JQuery & Datatable Date Filter

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a data table being populated by a foreach loop which contains a series of dates.  I have been asked to create buttons which fence off the dates.

My table Looks like:

```
<table class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ex. Date</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($emptyRenewal as $renewal) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo($renewal['EXPDATE']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo($renewal['CLIENTNAME']); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to create buttons above the table which fences off the results in the following ways, without re-loading the page.

```
0-30  days from today
30-60 days from today
60-90 days from today
```

What is the best way to do this?  I would assume that I pull all our clients, who's expiration dates are from 0-90 days away from today, and then sort them?  I just don't know how to do this without reloading the page.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us that code?

Comment: You could do 3 separate calls, selecting from the DB rows with dates within each date range.

Comment: I honestly havn't the faintest idea where to start.  I will give some things a shot and post them in a few.

Comment: @xd6_ - For 3 separate calls I would have to populate this datatable via ajax, right?  I have that set up now but I have to load the page each call.

Comment: @evade - I assume $emptyRenewal is a DB result array, so wherever you're generating that data you could call two more queries and store 3 arrays total. Array 1 would have all the 0-30, etc. so you can print a different table for each array or however you want to separate them.

Comment: @xd6_ - I really need to try to keep this within 1 table.  Having 3 tables is going to be considered as a waste of space.

Comment: Are we talking jQuery dataTables plugin here or just a table with data?